# $\cot(x)=\frac43 $ what is sin(2x)

Tags: trigonometry

You know that:
$$\cot(x)=\frac43 $$

$$π<x<\frac{3π}{2}$$

What is: $$\sin(2x)$$ and $$\cos(2x)$$

The solution must not contain trigonometric functions

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Look up the double-angle formulas for sine and cosine. With those, this question is routine, and without them, it may be difficult.

Comment: Well $\cot = \frac {\cos x}{\sin x} = \frac 43$ so $3\cos x = 4 \sin x$ and $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ so.... do something....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this geometrically. Suppose you have a right triangle with sides of $3$ and $4$. Hence,  its hypotenuse would be $5$. Now you can find easily $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ by their definition. Hence, $\sin(x) = \frac{3}{5}$ and $\cos(x) = \frac{4}{5}$. Now, you can find $\sin(2x) = 2 \sin(x)\cos(x) = 2 \times \frac{3}{5}\times \frac{4}{5} = \frac{24}{25}$.

[image]

Comment: I really like this approach

Answer (score 2):

We have $\tan x=\frac{3}{4}$ and $\sec^2 x=1+\tan^2 x=\frac{25}{16}$ so $$\sin 2x=2\tan x\cos^2 x=2\times\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{16}{25}=\frac{24}{25}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\cot x = \frac 43 = \frac ao$, then x is an angle in a 3,4,5 triangle, where the 3 is opposite the x, and 4 is adjacent to the x.

Thus, $\sin x = \frac oh=\frac 35$ and $\sin x = \frac ah=\frac 45$. The double angle formula gives 
$$\sin 2x = 2\cos x\sin x = 2\cdot\frac 35 \cdot\frac 45=\frac{24}{25}$$
You can find $\cos(2x)$ by using 
$$\sin^22x+\cos^2 2x=1$$
It's quite an elegant problem, really.

Answer (score 1):

If $\pi < x < \frac 32 \pi$ the $\sin x = -1$ and $\cos x = -1$.

Note $\frac {\cos x}{\sin x} = \frac 43$ so there is some value $m$ so that $\cos x = 4m$ and $\sin x = 3m$ and $1 = \cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = (4^2 + 3^2)m^2$ so $m = \frac 15$.

So $\sin x = -\frac 35$ and $\cos x = -\frac 45$.

$\sin 2x = $... gad I can never remember....

$\sin 2x = \sin x*\cos x + \sin x* \cos x = 2*\frac {-3*-4}{5*5} = \frac {24}{25}$ and

$\cos 2x = \cos x*\cos x - \sin x* \sin x = \frac {16}{25} - \frac {9}{25} = \frac 7{25}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the duplication formulæ:
$$\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x=2\sin^2x\cot x$$
Now from Pythagoras'identity, we know that $\;\cot^2x+1=\dfrac1{\sin^2x}$, so
$$\sin2x=\frac{2\cot x}{\cot^2x+1}=\frac{24}{25}.$$
On the other hand
$$\cos 2x=1-2\sin^2x=1-\frac{2}{1+\cot^2x}=\frac{\cot^2x-1}{\cot^2x+1}=\frac 7{25}.$$